# Isomorphism between a Module and its Homomorphisms to a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

So I just did an exercise to prove that if M is a finitely generated free module then $M \cong \operatorname{Hom}_A(M,A)$ when $A$ is a commutative ring , and I was wondering when does it fail ? So I started thinking about $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ as a module over $\mathbb{Z}$ but I'm not quite sure it fails? Can u guys help me out? Thanks.

Comment: It *always* fails if $M$ is a nonfinitely generated free module.

Comment: Alright Thanks , but can u be a little more specific like why does it fail in the example that i tried working it ? Im not really seeing it

Comment: It's easier if you consider $A$ a field. If $V$ is a nonfinitely generated vector space, then the dimension of the dual space is larger than the dimension of $V$.

Comment: Yeah i belive you , but im not really seeing how one goes about proving it, any sugestion ?

Comment: http://www.science.oregonstate.edu/~parks/sample338.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write $\mathbb Z^{\mathbb N}$, do you mean the direct sum $\oplus_{i \in \mathbb N} \mathbb Z$, or the direct product $\prod_{i \in \mathbb N} \mathbb Z$? Presumably you mean the $\oplus_{i \in \mathbb N} \mathbb Z$, since you're talking about free $\mathbb Z$-modules.

$\oplus_{i \in \mathbb N} \mathbb Z$ and $\prod_{i \in \mathbb N} \mathbb Z$ are different modules! In $\prod_{i \in \mathbb N} \mathbb Z$, every element can be uniquely expressed in the form $\sum_{i \in \mathbb N} a_i e_i $. In $\oplus_{i \in \mathbb N} \mathbb Z$, the elements take a similar form, except that there is the additional constraint that, for any element, *only finitely many of the $a_i$'s can be non-zero*. So $\oplus_{i \in \mathbb N} \mathbb Z$ is a strict submodule of $\prod_{i \in \mathbb N} \mathbb Z$.

It turns out that:

- ${\rm Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(\oplus_{i \in \mathbb N} \mathbb Z, \mathbb Z) = \prod_{i \in \mathbb N} \mathbb Z$.
- ${\rm Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(\prod_{i \in \mathbb N} \mathbb Z, \mathbb Z) = \oplus_{i \in \mathbb N} \mathbb Z$.

The first of these claims can be proved as follows. A $\mathbb Z$-module morphism  $f \in {\rm Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(\oplus_{i \in \mathbb N} \mathbb Z, \mathbb Z)$ is uniquely determined once you specify the images of the generators, $b_i = f(e_i) \in \mathbb Z$ for $i \in \mathbb N$. Any choice of $\{ b_i \}_{i \in \mathbb N}$ defines a valid $f \in {\rm Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(\oplus_{i \in \mathbb N} \mathbb Z, \mathbb Z)$, *and there is no restriction on whether the number of non-zero $b_i$'s is finite or infinite*. In other words, homomorphisms  $f \in {\rm Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(\oplus_{i \in \mathbb N} \mathbb Z, \mathbb Z)$ are in direct correspondence with elements $\{ b_i \} \in \prod_{i \in \mathbb N} \mathbb Z$.

The second claim is more difficult to prove - see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10239/is-it-true-that-as-bbb-z-modules-the-polynomial-ring-and-the-power-series-r/10249#10249)

Comment: I mean the direct sum sorry, but thanks for the answer!

Comment: @PedroSantos I answered for the direct sum.

Comment: Yes i know, thanks!!!!!

Comment: @KennyWong Sorry, my memory failed.

Comment: @egreg oh okay, no worries :)